# Copy files whose name matches row in a text file

Tags: shell

So I have one file, `filters.txt` that contains names like these:

```
01_0012
01_12321
02_123J4
...
```

And then there's a directory, `New/` with a lot of files named like this:

```
DEV_01_0012.csv
LIN_02_123J4.csv
FD_03_1234.csv
...
```

So I'm basically looking for a Unix way to copy all the files in `New/` that contain one of the patterns in `filters.txt`

I could write a Python script, but I can't really think of an easy way to do this with a shell script, if someone knows of a way I'd like to see it

Comment: What have you actually tried so far? Anything?

Comment: Wrote a Python script that does it but it's about 12 lines of code. I couldn't really think of a shell script one liner that does it so was wondering if someone else could figure one out as a learning experience for me

Comment: Hey I wrote a bash script which may also help those on here. https://github.com/jordyjwilliams/copy_filenames_from_txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty...

```
<filters.txt xargs -i% bash -c "eval cp *%* New/"
```

Comment: Yep this works, thank you. I'll add it to my toolbelt

Comment: Safer with `xargs -I {} sh -c 'cp *"$1"* New/' sh {}` since wonky filenames (`$(reboot)`) would not cause havoc.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an option:

```
for f in *.csv; do 
  [[ -n $(echo $f | grep -f filters.txt) ]] && cp $f dest/
done
```